# PHP how to print a query with SUM and math operators

Tags: php, mysql, sql, math, mysqli

I need to print a mysql (or better mysqli) query that contain math operators.
If I use a query like that

```
$sql = "SELECT SUM( `Home` + `Away`) AS Tot\n"
. "FROM `teams`\n"
. "WHERE `idteam` = \'Chelsea\'";
```

when I go to print the %result with mysql_result:

```
<?php echo mysql_result($result1,0); ?>
```

or with mysqli function:

```
$row=mysqli_fetch_array($result,MYSQLI_NUM);
printf ("%s \n",$row[0]);
```

it doesn't works.

The same code works if the Query ask to db just a simple information and not math operators like "SELECT SUM(a+b)*3"

Any ideas?
Thank you for support

Comment: can you tell us what you have in the DB?

Answer (score 0):

try

```
$sql = "SELECT  Home + Away AS Tot FROM teams WHERE idteam='Chelsea'";
```

SUM() is an aggregate function, your just adding 2 numbers

Comment: it should, its valid. it must be the php

Comment: I got the 5.4.23 version of PHP on my webserver

Answer (score 0):

$sql = "SELECT SUM(Home + Away) AS Tot FROM teams WHERE idteam='Chelsea'"; Works for me. I think the problem is in your php try

```
echo mysql_result[0];
```

Comment: it works if I perform this query into phpmyadmin panel, but it doesn't works when I try to print it in PHP.

Comment: try changing your echo statement to above. You are only returning one field with that statement.

Comment: Or are you trying to loop through all the returned records and print a line by line? if so you need to remove the SUM() command

Comment: Did you try echo mysql_result[0]; yet

Comment: it doesn't reports anything...
but mysql_result is deprecated and it doesn't works with mysqli. The best way is the fetch_array.

Tomorrow I'll try it on another webserver and I'll try to write again all the code.

Answer (score 0):

what if you try this?

```
$sql = "SELECT SUM(Home + Away) AS Tot FROM teams WHERE idteam='Chelsea'";
$res = mysql_query($sql);
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($res))
{
  echo $row["Tot"]."<br>";
}
```

(but this will print only one row)

Comment: noway... if you're sure about code, tomorrow I'll try on another webserver.

Comment: i am 100% sure about the code, but we haven't seen what you have in your DB and what exactly you want to get as a result.

Comment: tested on another webserver. It works fine.
Tomorrow, with some rest, I'll try to figure it out what was wrong
Really thank you for your support